# gray boxlike outline around text on hover

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a custom nav on bootstrap 3. A gray like box seems to appear around the text, whenever I hover around it,I've tried commenting on the a:hover code in my css, but the box still appears. Here's my code:

```css
 .navbar-custom {
    background-color:#36b;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-radius:0;
 height:68px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
    }
 
 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
     padding-left: 0;
     padding: 25px 0 75px 0;
     font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
     font-weight:300;
     font-size:13px;
 }
 
 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color:transparent;
 }
 
 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open >a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#ec6800;
 }
 .navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  color:#eeeeee;
 }

 .navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
  background-color:#eeeeee;
 }
 .navbar-custom .icon-bar {
  background-color:#33aa33;
 }
```

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
                 <div class="container">
     
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="signup.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;Login / Register</a></li>
                            </ul>
               </div>
                  </nav>
```

Comment: try adding this rule too "outline: none;" in a:hover and see if it works

Comment: I did try that, but it didn't work

Comment: then there must a rule in bootstrap.css that is overriding your settings.

Comment: I've tried virtually all I know, but it isn't working

Comment: Thanks for helping mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grey box is caused by the following css:

```
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

try overwriting it:

```
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out mate

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has it's own rule that you need to either change or override. It's:

```
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

You can set your own rule to something like:

```
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

**[Bootply example](https://www.bootply.com/hxx6UszhID)**

Comment: Thanks for reaching out mate